# How do I calculate the surface temperature of a star from luminosity?

Tags: star, temperature, luminosity

How do I calculate the surface temperature of a star from luminosity? I've been trying to delve into speculative solar systems for a bit, and I've heard the surface temperature of a star can be calculated from its brightness, but I can't find any ways to do that! Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: For a start, can you convert your luminosity to units of power and then use the [Stefan–Boltzmann_law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan–Boltzmann_law) and see what you get? It should be at least a good estimate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the temperature of a star](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13104/how-to-calculate-the-temperature-of-a-star)

Comment: make use of the radius-luminosity relation for main-sequence stars and assume a black body temperature.